# Embed coredata in a custom framework in iOS

Tags: ios, frameworks

I need to store some confidential information at the framework what I have created.

When I Did the same thing in my static library, the data model was shared along with the .a file.

Please give me an idea how to add core data in framework with out sharing the data model. If it is not possible please suggest any other possible way to store the data at framework side.

Comment: Your question is **too broad**. Stack Overflow is not a coding service, please ask only about short specific programming answers. Check [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on how to make questions on-topic.

Comment: Hi Nino,  Please give me an idea how to add core data in framework with out sharing the data model.

Comment: information like this are better suited as [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55139960/edit)